# mongoose find does not wait for completion

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Why does this code not wait for the find to finish and then return. It returns an empty array before the find completes.

```js
const findAllUsers = () => {
    const channelNames = [];

    ATwitchStreamer.find({}, (err, res) => {
        console.log(res)
        res.forEach((user) => {
            channelNames.push(user.username);
        });
    }).then(r =>
        return channelNames);
    return channelNames;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ATwitchStreamer.find` is a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You solve that by returning the promise chain:

```
return ATwitchStreamer.find(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

find method is an asynchronous function
so you could use async/await

```
const findAllUsers = async() => {
    const channelNames = [];

    await ATwitchStreamer.find({}, (err, res) => {
        console.log(res)
        res.forEach((user) => {
            channelNames.push(user.username);
        });
    })
    return channelNames;
};
```